# Why is my jQuery plugin not finding the TinyMCE editor on my page?

Tags: jquery, joomla, jquery-plugins, tinymce

I'm currently developing a website that incorporates TinyMCE editors on some of its pages. The site itself is working and the editors display on the proper pages.

I'm also working on a jQuery plugin that is supposed to bind events to the DOM elements on the page to handle events, such as change and click. Some of these events are also specific to TinyMCE editors, which is where the issue comes to light.

My written jQuery plugin works just fine in a simplified environment with just HTML on a static page, but when I moved it to the site I'm developing for, the TinyMCE events were not being bound to. I later discovered that `tinymce.editors` is an empty array, even on pages with an editor on them. To clarify, the editor is displayed on the page, but my plugin does not find it, thus `tinymce.editors` is an empty array.

Why is this happening? The plugin code is being included on that page as a JS script tag and it's placed at the bottom of the body tag, after the `tinymce.init()` call happens on the page.

More background info: The website is running on Joomla 3.6, which has TinyMCE installed as a plugin. Both are up to date as of this article being written. I've also noticed that the plugin does not add the custom CSS class to the TinyMCE editor after saving the class in the Jommla plugin using the admin section of the site. Could that be a related issue to the plugin issue I'm attempting to fix? Also to note, the events on regular inputs and other elements are working properly, so only TinyMCE is currently giving me issues.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my own issue. The TinyMCE editors were not fully initialized before my jQuery plugin was called, so the array of editors was empty. I wrapped the plugin code in a `setTimeout` block and was able to fix the issue, even with a 0 ms delay.